# Css : Justify child divs with variable width

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to justify child divs with variable width inside parent div with fixed width.I want to justify child divs not only on single line but inside the whole parent container.  
Parent and Child elements are dynamically generated.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1.2345</div>
    <div class="child">1:223345</div>
    <div class="child">1:23421225</div>
    <div class="child">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child">1:235</div>
    <div class="child">1:2345</div>
    .
    .
    .
    30 Child elements
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    width:450px;
    text-align:justify;
}
.child{
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

output is something like this

[image]

**UPDATED**
Now i have set width to each child divs depending on its text length.

Comment: Can you not add a width to the child divs?

Comment: i am dynamically generating the divs so adding width is not possible...as every child has different width

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .parent{
 width:250px;
 text-align:justify;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;

 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child{
 margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child">1.2345</div>
        <div class="child">1:2345</div>
        <div class="child">1:2345</div>
        <div class="child">1:2345</div>
        <div class="child">1:2345</div>
        <div class="child">1:2345</div>
        . . . 30 Child elements
    </div>
```

[demo add 30 +](https://jsfiddle.net/tgohguyj/)

Comment: child divs have variable width..and this works for equal width

Comment: I am dynamically appending child views to parent without setting their width in jquery n i want to justify those child views..I cannot set width for child..as their text is of variable length..

Answer (score 0):

Once all of your child divs have been added to the `DOM`, you could get the element with the greatest width and then set the width of each of the other divs.

```
var childDivs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.child"));
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, childDivs.map(function(ele){
    return ele.offsetWidth;
}));
for(var i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++){
    childDivs[i].style.width = maxWidth + "px";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS Flex box can do the job but you must ensure browser compatibility.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Also, there are a few concepts to understand before using flexbox. In the end, it can solve many CSS layout problems.

Ohterwise, you may need to use javascript to dynamically resize your elements.